# What size additional footing should be included in a monolithic slab for a 22'x32' carport columns?

Tags: foundation

In pouring a steel-reinforced monolithic slab for a 22' x 32' carport, the edges are to be thickened to 12" x 12" around the edges & 4" over re-wire in between.   Is 24" x 24" X 18" additional concrete w/steel and Simpson PA at each column location sufficient to meet code? The PA will be tied into the steel.

Comment: Usually the size will depend on the load and local regulations.  For a car port my opinion is it is big enough,  but your local building/planning office/inspector will know what is required for your conditions.  Might need to be bigger or maybe you can go smaller.

Comment: ...once again, you want details that depend upon loads that you have not specified.

Comment: Coastal SC enjoys a warmer climate that rarely goes below freezing, & even snowflakes here are rare.  We are close enough to the coast to experience the effects of periodic hurricane-force winds, thus Simpson PAs in the concrete & other hardware to tie foundation to roof down.